# nginx.conf appeared in all WordPress installations on folder

Tags: nginx, configuration

I run a couple of WordPress sites on a cloud server that I own. All of these sites run on the same Apache installation. Recently, I've found that in all of my WordPress webroot folders, an empty file called `nginx.conf` has appeared.

Should I be concerned (about a security breach)? I don't think WordPress creates an `nginx.conf` file on the webroot when updating or being installed. But I can't find anything about this on Google.

Comment: If you haven't already it's probably worth grepping your entire installation, including wp-content for plugins and theme, for nginx.conf to see if any of those might be doing it. I guess this is entirely self-hosted, i.e. you don't have WP Engine's mu-plugin or similar? Can you tell anything from the file ownership - i.e. was it written by the apache user - and timestamps on these files? If you delete them and update something do they come back? (e.g. you could clone a site and then update it to a beta channel if you're already on 5.1.1)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to `grep` my entire installation. I found the issue. I have the iThemes Security plugin installed on all my WordPress sites, and this causes `nginx.conf` to be created in the root folders when certain config settings are run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party but if anyone finds this as a result of a search.

this will have been auto-created when you installed Ithemes security.

By default, it will create an Nginx.conf file in the site public_html folder 
you can change the location of this file in the settings.

If it is on apache it shouldn't really do this though.